# Android App has more than one launcher

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have an app, with 2 activities. For some reason I am getting 2 launcher icons, one for each activity, but I only want one!

The Game activity had an intent-filter which i removed. I also uninstalled the app and reinstalled it from scratch but its still coming up with both launchers :(

Manifest below

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Game"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Delete the app and reinstall it

Comment: What are those reasons?? Can you please mention it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `label` tag from your second `Activity`.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Game" >
    </activity>
</application>
```